# alternative font display

Tags: fonts

I sometimes encounter content (such as an email I just received)  which specifies a font for the text (say, via a `<style>` tag) that I do not have installed (for example, MS's `Cambria`), and therefore it is displayed with some alternative font, which in my case is some horrible eyesore. I know I can always install the font in question, but sometimes you need a license, and sometimes that license costs money (sometimes a *lot* of money). So, I was wondering if there isn't some server, or plugin to the font server that can serve a "similar" font, or just an adequate font alternative from the ones already present on the system. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: You can use [identifont](http://www.identifont.com/similar.html) to find similar fonts.